# vertical array value store into mysql table different columns horizontally

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```js
function insert()
{

 var detail = [];




      for (var i = 0 ; i<= arrayA.length ; i++)
  {
    
  detail.push(arrayA[i]);
  
  }
 

 // });
 

$.ajax({  
    url:'insert.php',  
    method:"POST",  
    data:{  details: detail,},  
      
    success:function(data){  
    //alert(html);
    
    }  
   });  


}
```

```js
var arrayA = [];
function addvalues()

 
 $('[name=data]').each(function() {
     
 arrayA.push($(this).val());

 });
 
 
 alert("record enter");
}
```

I have pushed values from bootstrap form into array. Form entries are continuous like user fill the form and press add then after confirmation that values is added into array user again enter that form with different values and press add. after that user press submit to insert values into table. now form is like

```html
    <input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name ="data" type="text"  value="" id="name-input" required >
<input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name ="data" type="number"  value="" id="father-input" required>   
<input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name ="data" type="number"  value="" id="mother-input" required>
<input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name ="data" type="number"  value="" id="age-input" required >
<input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name ="data" type="number"  value="" id="blood-input" required >
<button type="button" id="add" onclick = addvalues();>Add</button>
```

and on pressing submit button all these values of an array insert into table

```js
 $sql1="INSERT INTO tble1 (name, father_name ,Mother_name,  age, blood_group)VALUES ";
 for($i=0;$i<count($values1);$i++) {
$sql1 .= " ('".$values1[$i]."', '".$values1[$i]."', '".$values1[$i]."','".$values1[$i]."','".$values1[$i]."'),";
 }
 $sql1_trimmed = rtrim($sql1,',');
```

But, this query enter value at 0 in all field. I want to enter value 0 in first field 1 in second and so on.

Comment: Proper indentation and grammar corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO tble1 (name, father_name ,Mother_name,  age, blood_group)VALUES ('";
for($i=0;$i<count($values1);$i++) {
   if($i == count($values1)-1){
        $sql1 .= $values1[$i]."')";
        return 0;
   }
   $sql1 .= $values1[$i]."', '";
}
```

But you shouldn't do insert in this way because it's dangerous it's called "sql injection"

You have to do it like this

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO tble1(name, father_name ,Mother_name,  age, blood_group) VALUES(:name, :father_name , :Mother_name,  :age, :blood_group)');
$req->execute(array(
    'name' => $values1[0],
    'father_name' => $values1[1],
    'Mother_name' => $values1[2],
    'age' => $values1[3],
    'blood_group' => $values1[4]
    ));
```

If you have an array like this

```
$values=[name,...., name, father_name, Mother_name, age, blood_group];
```

then just do like this

```
$values=array_chunk($values, 5);

for($i=0;$i<count($values);$i++) {
    $values1 = $values[$i];
$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO tble1(name, father_name ,Mother_name,  age, blood_group) VALUES(:name, :father_name , :Mother_name,  :age, :blood_group)');
$req->execute(array(
    'name' => $values1[0],
    'father_name' => $values1[1],
    'Mother_name' => $values1[2],
    'age' => $values1[3],
    'blood_group' => $values1[4]
    ));
}
```

Example

You got an array like this from your form

```
$values=[name0, father_name0, Mother_name0, age0, blood_group0, name1, father_name1, Mother_name1, age1, blood_group1];
```

it contain two sets of data `name0, father_name0, Mother_name0, age0, blood_group0` and `name1, father_name1, Mother_name1, age1, blood_group1`
it may contain n set of data but all of them have 5 values thats why I used

```
$values=array_chunk($values, 5);
```

it will split the array into n (in this example it will be 2 array) array

let's return to our example after doing `$values=array_chunk($values, 5);` 
values will be equal to

```
$values=[[name0, father_name0, Mother_name0, age0, blood_group0], [name1, father_name1, Mother_name1, age1, blood_group1]];
```

and using for loop we will loop over these sub arrays like this

```
for($i=0;$i<count($values);$i++) {
   $values1 = $values[$i];
   ....
}
```

For the JS code you are adding the same values multiple time do this instead

```
var arrayA = [];
function addvalues()

    var len = arrayA.length;
    for(let i=len; i<$('[name=data]').length; i++){
        if($('[name=data]')[i].val() || $('[name=data]')[i].val()==0){//if you aren't sure that these values can be null or not. Delete this line if you think that they can't be null.
           arrayA.push($('[name=data]')[i].val());
        }
     }

}
```

Also for the insert function do just this

```
    function insert(){
       $.ajax({  
             url:'insert.php',  
             method:"POST",  
             data:{  details: arrayA},  
             success:function(data){  
                             //alert(html);
                     }  
       });  
    }
```

Comment: did u read my form description? array is increasing on every entry. like at 0:name,1:fathername, 2:mothername, 3:age, 4:bloodgroup, 5:name, 6:fathername, 7:mothername, 8:age, 9:bloodgroup

Comment: @Sarah_Salar I edited my answer if you haven't understand somthing tell me

Comment: i donot understand the solutiom

Comment: @Sarah_Salar I will add an example

Comment: listen my insert values will be 200 or 300 so in this scenario this will not work

Comment: @Sarah_Salar It will work even if you have 10000 just try it

Comment: thanks a bundle for your explanation. but this is a problem i got array from form like name0,fathername1,mothername2,age3,blood4,name5 ,.....bloo9. array was appending after the entry

Comment: @Sarah_Salar can you post your js code and the html code of the form

Comment: i have added form code and js code of value has been added

Comment: @Sarah_Salar mark the question as answered if you find this answer good

Comment: thanks for your help but i figure out solution my self.